# check for value type as object in an array of objects- Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
array = [
{updated: "some date", hosts:{OS: "Windows"}},
{updated: "some1 date", hosts:{OS: "Linux"}},
{updated: "some2 date", hosts:{OS: "Won233"}},
{updated: "some3 date", hosts:{OS: "Mac"}},
]
```

In this I want to get all the values of the object in the array, however some values could be string and some could be object like in above case. HOw to check whether a array of object has a type value to it?
Note: the keys in the object are dynamic and hence I'm not able to do:

typeOf(array[0]["hosts"]) === "object"
 since this value will change every time the data gets generated,

```
    array.map(function(items){
          //since I have different keys here I'm not sure how
 to check for each key and check for the type of value against each key
    **these keys are dynamic and could change so I couldnt do** :
        typeOf(items.host) === "object"
        });
```

any clean way to do this?

Comment: sorry updated the code, it was a typo when I tyoed the code in...

Comment: Could you include some cases that illustrate the problem you're trying to resolve? All your objects have the same keys.

Comment: What result do you want?

Comment: `items.host` should be `items.hosts`.

Comment: Are you wanting to check if any property of an item is an object?

Comment: @Jacob: that is correct, I want to loop through the array of objects and check if any property is an object, if so get the key and value and store the value in another array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code segment provides you the keys of array of objects which have object as values.

```
array.forEach(item =>{
const keys = Object.keys(item)
.filter(k => typeof item[k] ==='object')
})
```

Try and run following code snippet which prints values of keys having value as object.

```js
const array = [
{updated: "some date", hosts:{OS: "Windows"}},
{updated: "some1 date", hosts:{OS: "Linux"}},
{updated: "some2 date", hosts:{OS: "Won233"}},
{updated: "some3 date", hosts:{OS: "Mac"}},
]

array.forEach(item =>{
const keys = Object.keys(item)
.filter(k => typeof item[k] ==='object')
keys.forEach(k => {console.log(item[k])})
})
```